# What does the nuget package MicroBuild.Core do?

Tags: visual-studio, build, nuget

In a Visual Studio 2017 project, I came across a nuget package called **MicroBuild.Core**.  Its nuget [page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicroBuild.Core/) has very little information (see below), and there is currently no content about it here on SO.  I know the pagkage is related to software builds, but what exactly does it do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the nuget package MicroBuild.Core do?

This package is used to load and execute other MicroBuild plugins during the build, which allow for the ability to override the plugin directory via the `MicroBuildOverridePluginDirectory` property, etc.

For more detail info, you can manual download this package, rename it with .zip, then unzip it, you will find three files in the packages:
[image]

Open file "`MicroBuild.Plugin.props`", there are a lot of detailed comments:

[image]

Hope this helps.